# How to achieve callbacks in WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have to create a WCF service that handles following tasks:

1. Register the notification sent from multiple client through WCF service.
2. The WCF service in turn sends ( Callback) the notification to the multiple client.

The WCF service also want to listen a datachange notification from another database server.

Can a WCF service is treated as a Listener that listen and send notifications for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Callback Contract, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx) , [blog post about it](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need is [duplex services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx).